# Magento Invoice PDF customization

Tags: magento, pdf, invoice

I am trying to do this to the standard Magento invoice pdf:

Write the Grand Total amount in words. For e.g. if the grand total is 457.30, I would like to be able to display Four Hundred and fifty seven point thirty.

I found this function: http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/convert-numbers-to-words-with-php/   that lets me convert numbers to words. But I can't get it to work. I added this to my invoice.php, and tried to use it, but it keeps giving me an error =- Call to undefined function convert_number_to_words().

How do I get this to work?
Thanks!

Comment: Where are you defining the function, and where is it being called? The error seems to indicate that the function isn't in scope when you call it.

Comment: I am define the function in the Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php. I am calling it in the same file.